# Spring bean scope and EJBs

Tags: spring, scope, ejb

I had been reading up on Spring framework documentation and came across this line.

> As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

Couldn't quiet digest it. Isn't the line above counter intuitive and just wrong? 
I could accept Stateful EJBs as Prototypal beans which makes sense but wouldn't it run against the very grain or idea of a Stateless EJB to declare it as a singleton bean?

[Spring bean scope and EJB](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) -- Read Section 5.5.2 - The Prototype Scope

Comment: What's the point of having dozens of instances of the same class, if all the instances have no state at all? All the instances would do exactly the same thing, so a unique instance is sufficient. Why do you think having many instances of a stateless bean would be better?

Comment: Scalability..... pool of Stateless beans managed by a container..... and so on....

Comment: A pool of beans is not more scalable than a single bean (it's actually less efficient, since you need to manage this pool). Multiple threads access the singleton concurrently. EJBs use pools of beans to allow the developer writing crappy, thread-unsafe code. Spring assumes you'll write your singleton bean code in a thread-safe way.

Comment: I am beginning to see the light. Spring offers the feature of an  SLSB to be a Singleton in the Spring's ApplicationContext(not the J2ee application context), which depending on the requirement, might or might not be needed by the developer...BUT SPRING OFFERS IT! So Thanks! With the advent of @Singleton bean in EJB 3.1 this has however become redundant. But I see the point of Spring's Singleton applicability.